# How should we do order_by in Django ORM for self-referred sub objects?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-orm

Have an issue with a somewhat problematic ordering/sorting in Django ORM. What I have is a Venue with a FK to `self`, thus the potential for sub-venues:

```py
# models.py
class Venue(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        to="self", related_name="children", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True
    )
    ordering = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Venue"
        verbose_name_plural = "Venues"
        ordering = ["ordering"]
```

Let's populate with some data:

```py
top = Venue.objects.create(name="Spain", ordering=0, parent=None)
Venue.objects.create(name="Barcelona", ordering=0, parent=top)
Venue.objects.create(name="Castelldefels", ordering=1, parent=top)
Venue.objects.create(name="Girona", ordering=2, parent=top)
top = Venue.objects.create(name="Singapore", ordering=1, parent=None)
```

This is how it looks like in the custom dashboard we've built. We're doing something akin to:
`Venue.objects.filter(parent__isnull=True)` and then, for each venue, we're doing `obj.children.all()`, thus creating this layout:

```
# find all parent=None, then loop over all obj.children.all()
Spain (ordering=0, parent=None)
- Barcelona (ordering=0, parent="Spain")
- Castelldefels (ordering=1, parent="Spain")
- Girona (ordering=2, parent="Spain")
Singapore (ordering=1, parent=None)
```

This is what we want to see when requesting our API endpoint:

```js
// json response
[
    {"venue": "Spain", "ordering": 0}, 
    {"venue": "Barcelona", "ordering": 0}, 
    {"venue": "Castelldefels", "ordering": 1}, 
    {"venue": "Girona", "ordering": 2}, 
    {"venue": "Singapore", "ordering": 1}
]
```

Problem is when we're calling the API, is that we're also using `django-filters` in our ModelViewSet thus we can't filter on `parent__isnull=True` or we won't see the children in the API response. We still have access to the queryset in the `def list`-method before returning it to the serializer.

Question is: how do we set the correct `.order_by()`? A simple `.order_by("ordering")` will place "Singapore" before "Girona" which would be wrong.

TYIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end we decided to go with a solution which in which we only used Python; saves us database lookups which can slow things to a crawl.

This is how we changed the ModelViewSet's list method:

```py
# overload modelviewset.list
def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
    all_venues = list(queryset)

    root_venues = []
    for venue in all_venues:
        if not venue.parent_id:
            root_venues.append(venue)

    venue_list = []
    for root_venue in root_venues:
        venue_list.append(root_venue)
        for venue in all_venues:
            if venue.parent_id == root_venue.id:
                venue_list.append(venue)

    serializer_kwargs = {
        "many": True,
        "context": {"request": self.request},
    }
    serializer = self.get_serializer(venue_list, **serializer_kwargs)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

By adding additional caching the response time is very fast.

Answer (score 0):

You can set default ordering in [Meta](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/models/#meta-options)

```
class Venue(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(to="Company", related_name="venues", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        to="self", related_name="children", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True
    )
    ordering = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
    # ...

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('ordering',)
```

`order_with_respect_to` can be useful too, see [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.order_with_respect_to)

Comment: Setting `Meta.ordering` won't help, as I explained in my last paragraph; "Singapore" would end up ahead of "Girona". 
I'm reading about `order_with_respect_to`, but I don't really see how it should work in my example. Venue.parent is to "self" so even a top-venue would also follow the same logic.

Comment: It's depend how you getting your output. According to code comment `# find all parent=None, then loop over all obj.children.all()` you getting childrens inside every parent in a loop with `obj.children.all()`, and they will be sorted as you need inside parent with ordering in Meta. If you want flat list of parents and children's, then yes, Meta ordering won't work

Comment: Yes, the children are being sorted by the `Meta.ordering` already. I'll update the question to show that it's already implied. The problem isn't necessarilty the ordering of the children, the problem is; how do I order the flat list?

Comment: I have an idea with a dirty hack when you write a order as a string like 0000001_1 in your parent, and 0000001_0000001 is written to his child, the next child is given 0000001_0000002, and the next parent is 0000002_1, and its child is 0000002_0000002, and so on. but this is, to put it mildly, not the most elegant solution but will work :) We'll have to check when creating that ordering string are assigned correctly to child and to parent

Answer (score 0):

you can also use -ve ordering in order by like this

Venue.objects.filter(parent__isnull=True).order_by("-ordering")